# Can I post back more values (e.g. ViewBag or Viewmodel values) when a DropDownListFor is selected?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller, dropdownlistfor

I have a DropDownListFor that is working fine. It's posting back the correct value as selected by the user. I'm trying to figure out if some of the Viewbag settings in the View can also be posted back to the controller (as query string items e.g. localhost:44346/Donation/IndexManage?Page=3&PageSize=20&SortOrder=ID).

Using javascript I am triggering the form to submit on change of the DDL items ... all working OK. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexManage", "Donation", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "DDL_PageSize" }))
{
    <div id="Paging">

        Records to Display:

        @Html.DropDownListFor(  
            // 1. Store selected value in Model.Donation.WalkerID;
            // when page is rendered after postback,
            // take selected value from Model.Donation.WalkerID.
            model => model.PageSize,

            // 2. Take list of values from Model.Walkers
            Model.PageSizeDDL,

            // 3. Text for the first 'default' option
            @Model.DisplayPageSizeDDL,

            //4. A class name to assign to <select> tag
            new { @class = "form-control form-control-md g-py-13 pr-0"})

    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#PageSize").change(function () {
            alert("Triggered by DDL");
            $("#DDL_PageSize").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName", FormMethod.Get, new { param1 = "param1", param2 = "param2 " }))`

Comment: Nope. That didn't work :-( But thanks.I think I found the solution - to use the Viewmodel's values as hidden in the form, and then use them when they're posted back.

Comment: if you add values as hidden then you are allowed to change that values in view.